# VBA - Check multiple comboboxes

Tags: vba, ms-access, if-statement, combobox

I have the below code where I'm trying to check comboboxes to make sure they are not null

I have a core combobox - cmbHierarchy - with Store, Retailer, Territory, District and secondary comboboxes to select stores, retailers, territories, districts (one for each)

I want the VBA to check cmbHierarchy to make sure it's populated, then depending on what it is populated with, make sure it's corresponding combobox has a value selected.

The current code is checking to make sure all 5 are populated. Where what I need is if cmbHierarchy = store then check cmbStore, if cmbHierarchy = retailer then check retailer, and so on.

```
Private Sub btnQryTermCount_Click()

 Dim strQueryName As String

 If Me.cmbHierarchy.Value = Store Or IsNull(Me.cmbStore.Value) Then
 MsgBox "Please choose a Store"
 Me.cmbStore.SetFocus

 ElseIf Me.cmbHierarchy.Value = Retailer Or IsNull(Me.cmbRetailer.Value) Then
 MsgBox "Please choose a Retailer"
 Me.cmbRetailer.SetFocus

 Else: strQueryName = "TERM_Count_" & Me.cmbHierarchy
 MsgBox "Query Ready: " & strQueryName
 DoCmd.OpenQuery strQueryName

End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your controls are named conveniently, you can do something like this:

```
If Nz(Me.cmbHierarchy.Value, "") <> "" Then
    If Nz(Me.Controls("cmb" & Me.cmbHierarchy.Value).Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a " & Me.cmbHierarchy.Value & "."
    Else
        strQueryName = "TERM_Count_" & Me.cmbHierarchy.Value
        MsgBox "Query Ready: " & strQueryName
        DoCmd.OpenQuery strQueryName
    End If
Else
     'cmbHierarchy validation failed logic here.
End if
```

IsNull instead of Nz maybe fine, but I am always in the habit of casting the value to be safe.